Pass Through Scroll Events from Child <div> to <canvas> (Excalidraw)
On my current project, I'm using Excalidraw, and I'm drawing a top layer of <div>s on top of the <canvas>. It all works fine, but, when it comes to scrolling through the infinite canvas, if the mouse is on top of one of the <div>s, scroll events won't pass through to the canvas below, so these <div>s are making the UX quite clunky.
Is there a way of having these <div>s not react to scroll events? I've tried something like pointer-events: none in CSS, and it works, but then the <div>s won't react to anything at all.
Here's a CodeSandbox with an example, which could be summarized by this code block:
"use client";

import { useMemo } from "react";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Excalidraw = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const mod = await import("@excalidraw/excalidraw");
    return mod.Excalidraw;
  },
  { ssr: false },
)

export default function Home() {
  const Excal = useMemo(() => <Excalidraw gridModeEnabled />, [])

  return (
    <main className="absolute w-screen h-screen">
      <div
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          zIndex: 100,
          top: "100px",
          left: "100px",
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
      >
        <p>here</p>
      </div>
      {Excal}
    </main>
  )
}


By scrolling events do you mean the ones generated using the mouse wheel? If so, I have to say that in my case the wheel makes no effect, regardless of where my mouse cursor is. BTW I'm on Chrome. Which browser do you use?

Just seen that if I expand to fullscreen,  message says to hold down the middle mouse button. Did you refer to this? In my case the panning happens even if i move over the label, but it doesn't work if I push down the button when I'm over the label. Is this the behaviour you want to change?

I mostly use the scrolling and panning gestures of the trackpad for those activities actually. And my current browser is Chrome.

Just to make everyone aware: you have to place at least one graphical element on the plan to see the scroll wheel working. Whan placing the cursor on the yellow label, the scroll doesn't work.

Well, I don't know how to edit the code in your sandbox, but I have succeded editing it in Chrome DevTools, so you can apply the same solution in your source code.
Basically you have to intercept the wheel event and manually dispatch it to the canvas.
I have assigned an ID (my123) to the yellow box to be able to reference it in my javascript code.
I have also created a variable to point to the canvas from our event handler:
myCanvas = $('.excalidraw__canvas.interactive')

and then
$('#my123').onmousewheel = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myCanvas.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel', {
        bubbles: e.bubbles,
        cancelable: e.cancelable,
        ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
        shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
        deltaX: e.deltaX,
        deltaY: e.deltaY,
        deltaMode: e.deltaMode
    }));
}

Passing ctrlKey and shiftKey properties allows to zoom and scroll horizontally too.
Be sure to set myCanvas after the canvas has been created.

You can fork the CodeSandbox, if you would like.

To achieve smooth scrolling on the Excalidraw canvas while having interactive <div> elements on top, you can utilize a combination of CSS and JavaScript. The goal is to ensure that scroll events pass through the top-layer <div> elements to the Excalidraw canvas while other events like clicks or drags remain interactive on the <div> elements.
Here's the updated code for your Home component:
"use client"

import { useMemo, useEffect } from "react"
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const Excalidraw = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const mod = await import("@excalidraw/excalidraw")
    return mod.Excalidraw
  },
  { ssr: false }
)

export default function Home() {
  const Excal = useMemo(() => <Excalidraw gridModeEnabled />, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const overlayDiv = document.querySelector(".overlay")
    if (overlayDiv) {
      const handleWheel = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault() // Prevent the default scroll behavior
        const excalidrawWrapper = document.querySelector(".excalidraw-wrapper")
        if (excalidrawWrapper) {
          excalidrawWrapper.scrollBy(event.deltaX, event.deltaY)
        }
      }

      overlayDiv.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel)

      return () => {
        overlayDiv.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <main className="absolute w-screen h-screen">
      <div
        className="overlay"
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          zIndex: 100,
          top: "100px",
          left: "100px",
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
      >
        <p>here</p>
      </div>
      {Excal}
    </main>
  )
}


That doesn't seem to be working on the CodeSandbox example I had provided. And, since I'm mostly using a trackpad, I've also tried it with DOMMouseScroll instead of wheel (shouldn't it be mousewheel?).

Could you maybe fork the sandbox and show something that works?

not entirely sure, but this sounds AI-generated
